# safari css animation bug

Tags: css, animation, safari, translate

This works fine in Chrome, but I get a weird effect in the latest Safari (& Safari Technology Preview, & Webkit nightly):  It's a simple CSS version of scrolling (like "marquee").  The text sits there instead of scrolling.  If I replace the background image with a background color, it works fine.  (Why would that be relevant?)  If I switch to a different tab & back, it works fine.  If I then reload the tab, it dies again.  Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body { background-image: url('http://insti.physics.sunysb.edu/~siegel/z-machine.jpg');
color:white }
@keyframes scroll {
0% { transform: translateY(100%); }
100% { transform: translateY(0%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
0% { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }
100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes scroll {
0% { -moz-transform: translateY(100%); }
100% { -moz-transform: translateY(0%); }
}
@-o-keyframes scroll {
0% { -o-transform: translateY(100%); }
100% { -o-transform: translateY(0%); }
}
.scroller {
height: 100%; vertical-align:top;
animation-name: scroll; -webkit-animation-name: scroll; -moz-animation-name: scroll; -o-animation-name: scroll;
animation-duration: 5s; -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 5s; -o-animation-duration: 5s;
animation-timing-function: linear; -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; 
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear; -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-iteration-count: infinite; -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite; -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height: 1000px; position: relative;"><p class="scroller">stuff</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```